# Part of CSS Code Not Rendering in Chrome

Tags: python, css, google-chrome, flask

This is my `main.css` file:

```
body {
    font-family: josefin;
}

.splash-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.register-button  {
    color: #6A136C;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #6A136C;
}

.btn {
    padding: 14px 24px;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn.sharp {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.btn.outline {
    background: none;
    padding: 12px 22px;
}

.btn-primary.outline {
    border: 2px solid #6A136C;
    color: #6A136C;
}

.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
}

.btn-primary {
    background: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background: #33a6cc;
}

.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active {
    background: #007299;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

However when I start my website and go to it, the styling isnt applied, then I go to the chrome dev-tools and look at the css, this is all that chrom shows:

```
body {
    font-family: josefin;
}

.splash-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.register-button  {
    color: #6A136C;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #6A136C;
}
```

And when I copy and paste the missing code, the styling works completely fine and the way it should, I have no clue whats going wrong or what Im doing wrong. Does anyone know what might be happening, this hasnt happened to me before. Im using flask, bootstrap, jquery, if that makes a difference.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you give us a live example of your code using jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you share your HTML too? Is correct reference of CSS file is applied?

Comment: Seems like possible browser cache issue if you recently updated. Check your CSS file in the browser and see if your code is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no errors in the CSS code.

The suggested list of steps to troubleshoot:

- Open the main.css file in an editor that displays "all characters" to make sure you don't have any non-displayable characters;
- Check the order of style sheets as they loaded in your HTML. Make sure the bootstrap styling is not overriding the custom styling (main.css should be the last file to load)
- Clear cache of your browser
- Make sure the server doesn't have caching enabled

```css
body {
    font-family: josefin;
}

.splash-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.register-button  {
    color: #6A136C;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #6A136C;
}

.btn {
    padding: 14px 24px;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn.sharp {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.btn.outline {
    background: none;
    padding: 12px 22px;
}

.btn-primary.outline {
    border: 2px solid #6A136C;
    color: #6A136C;
}

.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
}

.btn-primary {
    background: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background: #33a6cc;
}

.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active {
    background: #007299;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn btn-primary" value="test button"></input>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I moved main.css to be the last file to load and everything worked.

Comment: I am having a new problem, where the updates I make in the css code doesnt work when I restart the server and refresh?

Comment: I assume you are using a local server to test the code. I would recommend checking if there is any configuration of the caching enabled. Just to endure the issue is in the environment, not the code, try to upload the files to an online server.
Are you using any overrides (Chrome Dev Tool)?